# SUBQUERY in core data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, subquery

I can't understand what's wrong with my predication. I have the next database scheme:

```
DataItem(color_ids) <->> (dataItem)Color
```

Where Color contains colorID(int).

I tried to get

```
all DataItems that contain colorID == 5.
```

I have used the next predicate:

```
SUBQUERY(color_ids, $sub, $sub.colorID==5).@count > 0
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your clearly trying to use Core Data like SQL. Don't do that. Core Data is not SQL. Entities are not tables. Objects are not rows. Attributes are not columns. Relationships are not joins. Core Data is an object graph management system that may or may not persist the object graph and may or may not use SQL far behind the scenes to do so. Trying to think of Core Data in SQL terms will cause you to completely misunderstand Core Data and result in much grief and wasted time.

Comment: So what are we gonna do then. everyone"s first experience is sql (mostly mysql), when I read that coreData is sqlite based, I said ok I already did deal whit this.
But you are saying that we should not do that (I can say you are right after some grief I had already) .
So where Can I go to learn coreData the right way?

Answer (score 9):

You don't need `SUBQUERY` for this.  In fact, you almost *never* need `SUBQUERY`; it is **extremely** rare to find a situation where it is the correct thing to use.

You can do this instead:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY color_ids.colorID == 5"];
```

Comment: This works great. How would you go one level deeper? Say we have A <-->> B <-->> C. We have multiple A entities and C entities have an attribute called label. How can I find all A entities that contain C entities with label == @"1234"?

Comment: @zumzum For that you probably would need a `SUBQUERY`, and it'd be something like:  `SUBQUERY(aToBs, $b, ANY $b.bToCs.label = '1234').@count > 0`

Comment: Thanks. I'll work on this and will let you know how it goes as soon as I'm done. Do SUBQUERIES work on iOS?

Comment: I did exactly what Dave suggested above and it worked great. Thanks Dave!  Here's the exact predicate in case somebody wants the exact code I am using in case it helps.  NSPredicate * sp = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(catalogItemClasses, $b, ANY $b.catalogItems.label contains[cd] %@).@count > 0", searchText];

Comment: You can form it as an answer to your question and acept it, that would ve right way

Comment: Almost a decade later this was still very helpful, thanks so much.