# NSPredicate for nested sets

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

Say we have A <-->> B <-->> C. We have multiple A entities, and C entities have an attribute called label. How can I find all A entities that contain C entities that contain @"1234"?

I saw this [SUBQUERY in core data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890079/subquery-in-core-data/6890424#comment15997401_6890424) and it works great, but I'm basically trying to go one level deeper.

How could I achieve that?

thank you

Comment: Dave DeLong already gave you the answer, haven't he?

Comment: The answer has been given by Dave DeLong. Here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890079/subquery-in-core-data/6890424#comment15997401_6890424

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this question was given by Dave DeLong.

I am pasting here the one line of code that shows the subquery that worked for me in case it can help somebody else.

NSPredicate * sp = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(catalogItemClasses, $b, ANY $b.catalogItems.label contains[cd] %@).@count > 0", searchText];

So here the structure I am dealing with is A <-->> B <-->> C.
B entities are the "catalogItemClass" and C are the "catalogItem" entities.
This allows me to query for A entities that are related to C entities that have labels that contain the string searchText in them.

Thanks Dave.