# How to sort based on count of sub-relationship in Core Data?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I have a model like the following:

[image]

I am trying to query all the Users that have liked Posts on a certain pageId.  I only want returned in User.liked the Posts that match the given pageId.  Further, I want it sorted by the count of User.liked.

Can I do this all in one fetch?

My code so far:

```
NSFetchRequest* userFetch = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"User"];

NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(SUBQUERY(liked, $x, $x.page.pageId = %@).@count > 0)", self.pageId];
[userFetch setPredicate:predicate];

NSArray *allUsers = [_document.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:userFetch error:nil];
```

That correctly only gives me the User objects that have at least one like on a Page, but might include Posts from other Pages in User.liked.  Further, it isn't sorted.

I can sort post-fetch by doing this:

```
_users = [allUsers mutableCopy];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"liked.@count" ascending:NO];
_users = [[_users sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]] mutableCopy];
```

But that SLOOOOOOOWS everything down.  If there is no way to do the sort in the fetch, how can I speed up the sort post-fetch?

I am a CoreData newb, and when I get stuck like this I usually just end up just tossing CoreData altogether and start managing data by serializing my NSObjects out to disk.   Any tips before I do that here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, in subqueries you should use '*==*' instead of '*=*' So you could try with subquery:

```
@"(SUBQUERY(liked, $x, $x.page.pageId == %@).@count > 0)"
```

This might resolve the part `but might include Posts from other Pages in User.liked`

**Edited**

Comment: Unfortunately you can't use @ syntax sorts with to-many relationships.  :(

Comment: Also, as far as I know the SUBQUERY is just evaluating true/false, isn't it?  So basically, it will either return the User object, or not.  It won't filter it.   Plus I think '=' gets expanded to '==' anyway.

Comment: try to see this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890079/subquery-in-core-data Especially check out the comments to the only answer. Seems to me that the case there is almost yours except the need to make a sorting

Comment: and about the sorting you're right, you can't do it right along the fetch. I removed the 2nd part of my answer not to confuse somebody else. And in order to make the afterwards-sorting faster, you could try to have a look at Sorting and Filtering NSArray Objects: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/index.html